# Why did I get an ActiveRecord::Relation object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

I tried to get a car instance from database,

```
theCar = Car.where(:name => 'TOYOTA')
puts theCar.user_name
```

I got the error message: **undefined method `user_name' for
ActiveRecord::Relation:0xb6837b54**

Why did I get an **ActiveRecord::Relation** object, and not a **Car** object?? What could be the cause? By the way, I queried the car inside my migration file. I am using Rails 3.

Comment: Please note that Ruby is not a camelCase language. Use `the_car`, not `theCar`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You get it because you are using Lazy Loading. Nothing is loaded before you will call certain object or objects.

As a matter of fact your query will return an Array of objects: ALL cars with a name TOYOTA. If you know that there is only one CAR with this name you can do this:

```
theCar = Car.where(:name => 'TOYOTA').first
# or
theCar = Car.first(:name => 'TOYOTA')
# or
theCar = Car.find_by_name('TOYOTA')
```

And if there is many Cars with name TOYOTA:

```
theCars = Car.where( :name => "TOYOTA" ).all
theCars.map(&:user_name)
#=> ["Jhon", "Paul" ...]
```

Comment: In Rails 4, `SomeModel.where(something: true).all` is **deprecated**. Use `.to_a` instead. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18203898/1608670