# Rails 4 Relation#all deprecation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

In my app I created a recent posts feature.

```
 @recentposts = Post.all(:order => 'created_at DESC', :limit => 5)
```

This variable makes some trouble. When I run tests I have the following error:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Relation#all is deprecated. If you want to eager-load a relation, you can call #load (e.g. `Post.where(published: true).load`). If you want to get an array of records from a relation, you can call #to_a (e.g. `Post.where(published: true).to_a`). (called from show at /home/mateusz/rails4/Bloggers/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:18)

I was seraching solution on Google but I don't find it...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just write:

```
@recentposts = Post.order('created_at DESC').limit(5)
```

The `to_a` is not explicitly necessary, as the data is lazy loaded when needed.

Comment: While I'm all in for lazy loading, he was asking for the equivalent line. If he's migrating code, he probably wants to keep everything as close as possible to what it was right?

Comment: I try to think one step ahead. Yes, if identical is what the OP wants. Before there was no alternative, I personally believe it is better to only load the data when needed. E.g. this way you can still refine later and add scopes when needed. This can make for very clean code.

Comment: Yeah, I already said I'm all in for lazy loading but again, if he's just trying to migrate an app, keeping everything as close as it was is probably the best idea unless he knows enough about the app to change it.

Comment: So, if you think lazy loading is a good idea: why not migrate to it immediately? Normally it does not make a difference at all. The OP probably just  iterates over the posts in the view, so lazy loading is most likely perfect. The OP will decide if s/he can use it, and other readers with the same question as well. You do not have to agree with this answer.

Comment: If I wanted to disagree I would downvote it, which I haven't. I agree that your code is better, it's just dangerous to change core function calls like this. It normally doesn't make a difference, but it could and again, he's just interested in migrating the code, not improving it. I'm just saying it so that he's aware of it :)

Comment: Uhh... it is needed if you want to use `Rails.cache.fetch` as the non-eager loaded version will be saving nil records to your cache without the explicit call to #all or #load.

Comment: @tehprofessor that is true, because `Rails.cache.fetch` will not try to iterate over the results, just store whatever you hand it. Note: in rails 4 `all` is a `Relation` (so it will not load anything either).

Answer (score 10):

A call to `Post.all` will return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, which will be loaded lazily by default. Calling `Post.all.load` will return an eagerly-loaded `ActiveRecord::Relation`. Finally, calling `Post.all.to_a` will return all records in an array.

In your case you would do:

```
Post.order('created_at DESC').limit(5).to_a
```

which would return an array of the first 5 Posts, sorted by `created_at` in descending order.

Comment: Not sure what you are proposing in the second line, but that does not work at all.

Comment: If I use to_a directly on the class, I get the error: `undefined method `to_a' for #<Class:0x007fa23b6d6750>` in Rails 4.

Comment: I also find that I get 
``undefined method `to_a' for #<Class:0x0000010870d768>``

Anyone know how I just load all instances of my model?

Comment: @LaurieYoung This is unfortunately a misleading answer. To be clear, `Model.all` has **not** been deprecated, but (for example), `Model.where(something: true).all` has been deprecated in favour of `Model.where(something: true).load` if you wanted to eagerly load the data and `.to_a` if you explicitly wanted an array of the records to be returned. Reference: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/12904#issuecomment-28617504

Comment: @Hallucynogenyc Quick on the draw! There's still a slight problem though, as it should be `Model.all.to_a` as `to_a` isn't defined on models... I'll make a quick edit, see what you think.

Comment: Great, that's much better :D

Answer (score 2):

Nested way

```
Post.order('created_at DESC').limit(5).to_a
```

Comment: Thank's everyone for help :)

Comment: @MateuszUrbański so, if you already had your answer, give some love and mark the chosen answer as correct