# Rails 3.2.13: Stop ActiveRecord Lazy Loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Whenever I run a where clause the query is not executed until I try to access the actual data from the results. Is there anyway I can make it automatically execute.

Example:

```
delete_list = Rom::Leaderboard.where("pvp_type = ? AND server_id = ?", pvptype, server_id)
```

delete_list now holds an ActiveRecord object. But I want it to hold the resulting array without having to run something like

```
delete_list.each ...
```

Comment: could you try `delete_list.delete_all`?

Comment: yes i am doing that later. but there is a reason why I need the delete_list to hold the actual array before I run delete_list.delete_all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an entire query eagerly loaded you can use `.all` like:

```
delete_list = Rom::Leaderboard.where(...).all
```

This will result in `delete_list` being an array.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I swore I tried this and it failed saying no method error. Thank you!

Comment: In Rails 4, `SomeModel.where(something: true).all` is **deprecated**. Use `.to_a` instead. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18203898/1608670

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are just trying to delete, calling `destroy_all` or `delete_all` runs immediately

```
Rom::Leaderboard.where("pvp_type = ? AND server_id = ?", pvptype, server_id).destroy_all
```

OR

```
delete_list = Rom::Leaderboard.where("pvp_type = ? AND server_id = ?", pvptype, server_id)
delete_list.destroy_all
```

As for the difference between `destroy_all` and `delete_all`.

- `destroy_all`: The associated objects are destroyed alongside this object by calling their destroy method. This will effectivly loop through each object, calling `destroy` on it. So, you will have at least 1 query per object.
- `delete_all`: All associated objects are destroyed immediately without calling their :destroy method. This basically creates a single `delete from leader_boards` query using your where clause. So, no matter how many objects you have, it only runs 1 query. However, any associated objects are not cleaned up.